# How to stream the removed items in java removeIf?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm using `removeIf` to remove certain objects from a list if their name or code is null:

```
tables.removeIf(t -> ((t.getName() == null) || (t.getCode() == null)));
```

Is there a way I can get the actual items `t` that have been removed here? Maybe a list of the removed items, or better yet, a stream of the removed items?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can partition by your criterion and then use the result for whatever you want:

```
Map<Boolean, List<MyClass>> split = tables.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(t -> 
                t.getName() == null || t.getCode() == null));

List<MyClass> cleanList = split.get(Boolean.FALSE);
List<MyClass> removedList = split.get(Boolean.TRUE);
```

`cleanList` contains what `tables` would have contained after `removeIf`, and `removedList` data that was discarded (the one you were looking for)

Comment: Beat me by 2 minutes ;)

Comment: :-) It may be the first time I achieve the feat!

Comment: I like this solution, better than mine ;)

Comment: thanks @YCF_L - but I think your post didn't need to be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

What about make it in two steps :

find objects you want to remove:

```
List<ObjectName> toBeRemoved = tables.stream()
        .filter(t -> t.getName() == null || t.getCode() == null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and then remove them from the list :

```
tables.removeAll(toBeRemoved);
```

Comment: Or, of course, you could do it with an iterator loop, adding the items to a list as you remove them.

Comment: @AndyTurner exactly

Comment: May be important to note that this assumes that `ObjectName` has `equals` and `hashCode` correctly overridden.